# Error trying to get upsert behavior in Airflow PostgresHook

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I'm using the following to update values in a table where the key is `(team, year)`:

```
pg_conn.insert_rows('kenpom',
                    list(df.itertuples(index=False)),
                    target_fields=['rank',
                                   'team',
                                   'ortg',
                                   'drtg',
                                   'year'],
                    replace=True)
```

My assumption was that using `replace=True` makes this behave like an `upsert` but I'm getting the following error:

```
[2021-09-10 12:36:51,901] {taskinstance.py:1462} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1164, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1282, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1312, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 150, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 161, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/evan/airflow/dags/top_lines_daily_pipeline.py", line 28, in _update_kenpom_table
    pg_conn.insert_rows('kenpom',
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi.py", line 305, in insert_rows
    sql = self._generate_insert_sql(table, values, target_fields, replace, **kwargs)
  File "/home/evan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 239, in _generate_insert_sql
    raise ValueError("PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT upsert syntax requires an unique index")
ValueError: PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT upsert syntax requires an unique index
```

I don't understand `ValueError: PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT upsert syntax requires an unique index` because there *is* a unique index in the table. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `replace_index` parameter in your function.

`PostgresHook` acts differently than other hooks because of different syntax. Noramly the `replace=True` is enough. However this changes the sql from `INSERT INTO` to `REPLACE INTO` - which is not valid for `PostgreSQL`([source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4ee8f82d482974b634a81cb684703c01ef6ce7c4/airflow/hooks/dbapi.py#L289-L292)).
For that reason `PostgresHook` has its own implementation which require additional parameter: `replace_index`. The `replace_index` is the column or list of column names to act as index for the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

The statement that you want to create is:

```
INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT ({}) DO UPDATE SET {}
```

The `replace_index` handles the columns that will be in the `ON CONFLICT ({})`

You can view the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4ee8f82d482974b634a81cb684703c01ef6ce7c4/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py#L247-L249) that generates it.

Comment: For those who are looking for an example:  
 `dest.insert_rows(table="Members", rows=cursor,replace=True,replace_index="id",target_fields=['id','memberId','firstName','secondName'])`